# Can elliptic integral singular values generate cubic polynomials with integer coefficients?

Tags: elliptic-curves, integral-transforms, algebraic-number-theory

For the elliptic integral of first kind, $K(m)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-m^2sin^2\theta}} $, it is well-known that $K(m)$ can be expressed in what Chowla and Selberg call "finite terms" (i.e. algebraic numbers and a finite product of Gamma functions of rational values) whenever $i\frac{K(\sqrt{1-m^2})}{K(m)}$ belongs to an imaginary quadratic field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{d})$
(see Theorem 7 in S. Chowla and A. Selberg, [On Epstein's zeta function, J. reine angew. Math. 227, 86-110, 196](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1063041/pdf/pnas01544-0031.pdf)).

Examples for these so called **elliptic integral singular values** are given on [this Wolfram page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValue.html) (with some small typos) and in the note of J.M. Borwein and I.J. Zucker, "Elliptic integral evaluation of the Gamma function at
rational values of small denominator," [IMA Journal on Numerical Analysis, 12 (1992), 519-
526](http://carma.newcastle.edu.au/jon/Preprints/Books/EMA/Exercises/For%20others/K-beta.pdf).

See also what Tito Piezas has to say about this in his pleasant-to-read [Collection of Algebraic Identities](https://www.sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/0026).

The following question arises:

- **For these singular values, is there** (always, or, if not always: when?) **a polynomial $P(t)$ of degree 3 with *integer* coefficients such that $K(m)=c\int\limits_{t_0}^\infty\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{P(t)}} $ with $c\in\mathbb Q$?**
  (EDIT: After Noam Elkies' remark, introduced $t_0$, the biggest real zero of $P$, instead of $0$ as the lower limit. Only "complete" integrals make sense here.)

In particular for $d=-7$, we have by the [Carlson symmetric form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlson_symmetric_form) $$\frac12\int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{t(t+1)(t+\frac{8+3\sqrt 7}{16})}} =K(k_7)=\dfrac1{7^{1/4}4\pi}\Gamma\left(\dfrac17\right)\Gamma\left(\dfrac27\right)\Gamma\left(\dfrac47\right),$$ on the other hand I have seen somewhere (I can't remember the reference) $$\int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{t(t^2+21t+112)}} =\dfrac1{4\pi\sqrt{7}}\Gamma\left(\dfrac17\right)\Gamma\left(\dfrac27\right)\Gamma\left(\dfrac47\right)=\frac{K(k_7)}{7^{1/4}}.$$

I would like to get it straight at least for this example:

- **Can the polynomial in the first integral be transformed into one with integer coefficients? And is there any sort of relationship between both above polynomials?**
  Note that the ratio of the discriminants of the two above polynomials is $-2^{24}\cdot7^3$, and both of them do *not* yield affirmative answers, as the second one would have to be divided by $\sqrt7$ to obtain $K(k_7)$ directly!
- **EDIT: Follow-up question: If $P(t)$ is an integer cubic polynomial such that $\int\limits_{t_0}^\infty\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{P(t)}} $  (with $t_0$ its biggest real zero) can be written in "finite terms", is this value always an algebraic multiple of an elliptic integral singular value $K(m)$?**

Comment: Is this really about elliptic curves with complex multiplication? If so, then the answer is going to be yes if and only if the class number of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{d})=1$.

Comment: I didn't necessarily think of that restriction. So if we restrict them to that, which polynomial(s) would that be for the $d=-7$ case? And how to find them? Unique?

Comment: If I understand what is going on correctly, any polynomial with the same $j$-invariant should do: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant#Algebraic_definition

Comment: spanferkel's demand that the integral be over $(0,\infty)$ means that the curve must also have a rational 2-torsion point, which cuts the usual list of 13 CM discriminants down to seven:
$$-3, -4, -7, -8, -12, -16, -28.$$ For example, the disc.-11 curve yields the complete elliptic integral of $dt / \sqrt{4t^3-4t^2-28t+41}$ which is a rational multiple of $$\pi^{-2} \phantom.\Gamma(1/11)\phantom.\Gamma(3/11)\phantom.\Gamma(4/11) \Gamma(5/11)\phantom.\Gamma(9/11),$$ but the cubic is irreducible so the integral cannot be written as $\int_0^\infty dt/\sqrt P(t)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have edited the lower limit, as it is exactly examples like yours I'm interested in. I suppose the curve is uniquely determined by $d$, up to translation? So again the question: What about $n=-7$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The flurry of comments did not yet produce an answer to the question
concerning the complete elliptic integrals
$$
I_1 := \frac12
\int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{t(t+1)(t+\frac{8+3\sqrt{7}}{16})}}
$$
and
$$
I_2 := \int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{t(t^2+21t+112)}}.
$$
It turns out that (i) Yes, $I_1$ can be transformed to a complete
elliptic integral associated to a cubic with integer coefficients, and
(ii) The identity $I_1 = 7^{1/4} I_2$ can then be recovered via
a form of
Landen's transformation.

This could be surmised by calculating the $j$-invariants of the
corresponding elliptic curves 
$$
y^2 = x(x+1)(x+\frac{8+3\sqrt{7}}{16})
\phantom{\cong}\text{and}\phantom{\cong}
y^2 = x(x^2+21x+112).  
$$
The first $j$-invariant is $j_1 = 16581375 = 255^3$, which is rational,
so there's a linear change of variable that transforms
$x(x+1)(x+\frac{8+3\sqrt{7}}{16})$ to a polynomial with integer coefficients.
The second $j$-invariant is $j_2 = -3375 = -15^3 \neq j_1$, so we can't
get immediately from $j_1$ to $j_2$.  But $j_1$ and $j_2$ are still
related by a $2$-isogeny [indeed $j_1 = j(\sqrt{-7})$ and
$j_2 = j((1+\sqrt{-7})/2)$], so $I_1$ and $I_2$ are related by
a Landen transformation.

For (i), first translate $t$ by $(8+3\sqrt{7})/16$ to get
$$
I_1 := \frac12
\int\limits_{\frac{8+3\sqrt{7}}{16}}^\infty
 \dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{t
   \bigl(t-\frac{8+3\sqrt{7}}{16}\bigr)
   \bigl(t-\frac{-8+3\sqrt{7}}{16}\bigr)
 }} \phantom{0}.
$$
Then observe that
$$
   \bigl(t-\frac{8+3\sqrt{7}}{16}\bigr)
   \bigl(t-\frac{-8+3\sqrt{7}}{16}\bigr)
= t^2 - \frac{3\sqrt{7}}{8} + \frac{3^2 7 - 8^2}{16^2}
= t^2 - \frac{6\sqrt{7}}{16} - \frac1{16^2}.
$$
Thus the change of variable $x = 16 \sqrt{7} \cdot t$ yields
$$
I_1 = 2 \cdot 7^{1/4}
\int\limits_{21+8\sqrt{7}}^\infty
 \dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{x (x^2-42x-7)}}
$$
with the integrand having integer coefficients.

For (ii), we apply Landen's change of variable for elliptic integrals
$\int dt/\sqrt{t(t^2+at+b)}$ with $a,b>0$: if $x = (t^2+at+b)/t$ then
$dt/\sqrt{t(t^2+at+b)} = dx/\sqrt{x(x^2+Ax+B)}$ where $(A,B) = (-2a, a^2-4b)$.
Moreover the map $t \mapsto (t^2+at+b)/t$ maps the interval $0 < t < \infty$
to $a + 2\sqrt{b} \leq x < \infty$, with each $x$ value arising twice
except for the left endpoint $x = a+2\sqrt{b}$ which has a single preimage
$t = \sqrt{b}$ of multiplicity $2$.  Therefore
$$
\int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{t(t^2+at+b)}} =
2 \int\limits_{a+2\sqrt{b}}^\infty\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{x(x^2-AX-B)}}.
$$
The $I_2$ coefficients $(a,b) = (21,112)$ yield $(A,B) = (-42,-7)$ and
$a + 2 \sqrt{b} = 21 + 8 \sqrt{7}$.  Therefore $I_1 = 7^{1/4} I_2$ as desired.

Comment: May I request your expertise in the topic for solving a similar problem, namely http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1326557/integral-large-int-0-infty-fracdx-sqrt47-cosh-x ?